# Deleting a list that does not meet a specific criteria?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm a bit confused on how to approach this problem.

I have a large number of lists and am looking to delete lists have contents that do not start with a specific digit.

For example. say I'm looking to only keep lists that have at least one node that start with 4 in the following lists:

```
['4-7', '2-5', '2-9', '2-32', '2-16', '2-29', '2-13', '2-26', '2-20', '2-23']
['2-32', '2-31', '2-36', '2-28', '2-34', '2-43', '2-41', '2-39']
```

I should delete the second one and keep the first list, in this case.  I know how to detect which ones start with 4 and I can figure out the lists that have that trait but not sure how to mark the other lists for deletion.

What's the best approach? I have many lists like this(several million) so I am trying to find the least expensive way to do this. I was thinking of creating a list to lists to keep and then comparing it with original list and delete the ones that aren't on both lists, but I am trying to avoid too many nested for loops.

Comment: Where are you trying to delete them from? A file, a database, a variable?

Comment: sorry should have mentioned that.  I created a graph with nodes and edges(paths).  I am trying to delete all the broken paths. So I have a list of nodes that I can list as a list using a for loop and I can see all the edges they have(which is what I posted in my example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a list comprehension:

```
result = [yourlist for yourlist in yourlists
          if any(node.startswith('4-') for node in yourlist)]
```

Or a generator expression if you don't want to have the results in memory all at once:

```
result = (yourlist for yourlist in yourlists
          if any(node.startswith('4-') for node in yourlist))
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/yaKt9)

Comment: wow..I thought that was pseudo code when I read it, then opened your link and realized its real code.  I didn't know about those commands.  Thanks.

One more question, is better to use generator expressions if I am doing all this in a for loop with variables that are being overwritten each loop?

Comment: @Lostsoul: It's hard to tell without knowing more about your code, but if the input is a list of lists and it comfortably fits in memory, the simplest is probably to use a list comprehension and assign it back to `yourlists` so the original list gets garbage collected. If it doesn't comfortably fit in memory, the answer might be more complicated depending on what it is you need to do with the result. A generator expression is useful if you just want to iterate over it, but  not so useful if you want random access.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  My list is large but can fit in memory.  Thanks for the answer and the great follow up explanation.